# jQuery - Toggle content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I toggle the button text once the content is visible? How can I hide the content if I click on the button again?

Here is what I mean: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/0gctxtmv/)

I want to change the button text from View content to Hide content and the icon class from `fa-arrow-circle-down` to `fa-arrow-circle-up`

```
$('.js-show-content').bind('click', function(){
    $(".content").slideDown(200);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.js-show-content').bind('click', function(){
    $('.content').slideToggle(200);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-arrow-circle-down fa-arrow-circle-up');
    $(this).find('span').html(function(i, text){
      return text === 'Hide content' ? 'View content' : 'Hide content';
    });
    return false;
});
```

Additionally you will have to modify the HTML slightly by wrapping the button text in a `span` so that when you modify the text you do not remove the `i` element:

```
<a class="js-show-content btn btn-default" href="#" role="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-md"></i> <span>View content</span></a>
```

As others have stated, you can use jQuery's [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) to show/hide the `.content` div using a single line of code. The next part uses [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to switch between the `up` and `down` arrow icons on the `i` element. Finally, we are swapping out the text with a simplified [if/else statement](http://css-plus.com/2011/07/jquery-if-else-statements/) which checks the current text of the button, if it matches then the text is changed, if it doesn't match then it switches back to the initial text.

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gctxtmv/6/)

Comment: No need to call `toggleClass` twice. You can pass in class names in a list separated by spaces. `.toggleClass('fa-arrow-circle-down fa-arrow-circle-up')`.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/0gctxtmv/

I don't know about your button text, but now it toggles back up again when you reclick

```
$('.js-show-content').bind('click', function(){
    $(".content").slideToggle(200);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a built-in function called `.slideToggle()` which you can read about here: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Other than that, you will just have to use conditionals to change the CSS properties, although I would suggest, if you are using your own CSS to make a default CSS property the arrow down, and when you click add a class that overrides that arrow. Click again- remove the override CSS class and restore the button back to default

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect using jquery slide toggle.

```
$( ".js-show-content" ).click(function() {
  $( ".content" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to do it:

```
$('.js-show-content').bind('click', function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    $(".content").slideToggle(200, function () {
        // Toggle button content            
        if (btn.find('.fa-arrow-circle-down').length)
            btn.html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-md"></i> Hide content');
        else
            btn.html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-md"></i> View content');
    });
    return false;
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0gctxtmv/4/